# Long text input from user and PDF generation

Tags: java, pdf-generation, jasper-reports, validation, ireport

I have built a web application that can be seen as an overcomplicated application form. There are bunch of text areas with a given character limit. After the form submission various things happen and one of them is PDF generation.

The text is queried from the DB and inserted in the PDF template created in iReports. This works fine but the major pain is overflowing text.

The maximum number of characters is set based on 'average' text. But sometimes people prefer to write with CAPS or add plenty of linefeeds to format their text. These then cause user's text to overflow the space given in PDF. Unfortunately the PDF document must look like a real application form so I cannot allow unlimited space.

What kind of approaches you have used to tackle this?

- Clean/restrict user input?
- Calculate the space requirement of the text based on font metrics?
- Provide preview of the PDF? (too bad users are not allowed to change their input after submission...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, calculate the requirement based on metrics. I don't know how iReports handles text, but with iText, it lays everything out itself, you just present the data as a streaming document, so we don't worry about overflowing text.

However, iReport may not support that, or you may need to have the PDF layout fit within certain bounds. I'd try to clean the input (ie: if it's all caps, lowercase/sentence case/proper case it), strip extra whitespace. If cleaning the input can't be reliably done, or people are still getting past that, I'd also restrict it.

As a last resort, I'd present the PDF for the user to authorize. Really, users shouldn't be given more work to do, and they're not going to do it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Your own suggested solutions to your problem are all good.  Probably the most important question to have answered is what should your PDF look like when the data to be displayed in a field won't fit?  Do you ever need the "full answer" for anything else?  When you know the answer to these, you'll have your options reduced.

For example if a field must be limited to 1/2 a page, and users sometimes enter more than 1/2 a page of text you can either
  1) limit the user input - on submission calculate the size (using font-metrics as you said) and reject the submission until corrected.  This assumes you can legitimately force the user to reduce their data entry.
  2) accept the user input and truncate in the display of this report.  Some systems use "..." to indicate data has been truncated, and can provide a hyperlink (even within the PDF) to get more information.

Providing a preview would work really well, but only if the users are good at checking and correcting and your system can handle the extra load this will generate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control of the font that is used when generating the PDF?  If so, I would look for a font in the Monospace family.  This will give you consistent length for a given number of chars, regardless of puncuation, capitalization, etc.